# What does it mean that light "will not reach your eye unless your eye is positioned at just the right place" in specular reflection?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics

I am confused about the following passage from my textbook:

> When light is incident upon a rough surface, even microscopically rough such as this page, it is reflected in many directions, as shown in Fig. 23-3. This is called diffuse reflection. The law of reflection still holds, however, at each small section of the surface. Because of diffuse reflection in all directions, an ordinary object can be seen at many different angles by the light reflected from it. When you move your head to the side, different reflected rays reach your eye from each point on the object (such as this page), Fig. 23-4a. Let us compare diffuse reflection to reflection from a mirror, which is known as specular reflection. ("Speculum" is Latin for mirror.) When a narrow beam of light shines on a mirror, the light **will not reach your eye unless your eye is positioned at just the right place where the law of reflection is satisfied**, as show in in Fig. 23-4b. This is what gives rise to the special image-forming properties of mirrors.

[image]

The highlighted part is unclear. It is said that vision doesn't occur if I am not at the right position but I see the image as well as I am in front the mirror. So what is the meaning of the highlighted part?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines; for formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead. I have transcribed this image for you but you should do this yourself in future. You should also use descriptive titles that actually describe the question.

Comment: Re. "I see the image as well as I am in front the mirror." The "source" in that diagram is not an "image." The source is a laser-like beam (a tight bundle of parallel rays.) When a laser-like beam reflects off a flat, polished surface, the reflection also is a laser-like beam. (Don't stare into the beam!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I see the image as well as I am in front the mirror

It's because light reflected from you and striking mirror after is of **diffuse reflection** type. So each your body point acts as ambient light source, which sends bunch of light rays to different directions, part of them who passes to the right angle onto the mirror towards your eyes. So mirror forms specular reflection, but your body - diffuse. That's main point why you see yourself in the mirror being even straight in front of it.

To check the fact of pecular reflection of mirror you need to shine parallel rays, for example **laser**, into a mirror and you will notice that laser dot will be positioned at some reflected angle, which illustrates the fact that **other directions** doesn't see laser light being reflected.