# Minimum length of full-length mirror - can anyone explain?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics

[image: ..]

this example by the answer but I don't understand the steps. So please if you understand or have another steps drop it . Thanks

Comment: As you have [just been told](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/573826/what-does-it-mean-that-light-will-not-reach-your-eye-unless-your-eye-is-positio#comment1293365_573826), [screenshots of text have no place on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563): type it out instead, so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). Similarly, nondescriptive titles like this are simply not useful.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I have edited the title to make it more descriptive. It wasn’t difficult.

Comment: @gandalf61 Indeed, and I did the same for OP's first post, along with indicating that OP needs to that themselves in future posts. To be blunt, this is a bad question, with extremely limited effort put into it -- generally speaking, when asking a question, one should put in as much effort as one expects the potential answerers to put into their answers.

Comment: It may help if you re-draw the diagram to show how it looks when the person stands at different distances from the mirror.

Comment: Please be more specific about what is confusing you, and as Emilio Pisanty has mentioned please type out whatever parts of your textbook are relevant rather than just posting an image of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the given solution is overly complicated.

Since we know that the woman’s virtual image is the same height as she is and is twice as far from her as the mirror, then her image in the plane of the mirror must be half her height i.e. $80$ cm. So the mirror must be at least $80$ cm high.

Similarly the top of her head is $10$ cm abover her eye line so the top of the mirror must be $5$ cm above her eye line i.e. at a height of $155$ cm. And the bottom of the mirror is $80$ cm below this, so at a height of $75$ cm.